# Override the NewCase Action with a Lightning Component that launches a Flow in a pop-up

Tags: lightning-aura-components, screen-flow, lightning-modal, lightning-action-override

### Overview

We've built a custom screen flow to guide Users through creating a new Case record. We would like this flow to override the standard "NewCase" action, so that when a User clicks it, the Flow runs in a pop-up similar to the experience for when you try to create a new record using the standard "New" button.

After some research, it seems like I will need to use a Lightning Component to override the action and launch the Flow in a pop-up. I've taken a crack at putting a component together, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I click the "New" button, it loads a NEW screen (rather than launching the modal on the existing list view page) and nothing renders in the pop-up. I've tested my Flow extensively and it works fine launching from being embedded on a page or a custom button.

It might be worth noting that I am using record fields ([Dynamic Forms for Flow](https://unofficialsf.com/dynamic-forms-for-flow-overview/)) in my screen flow. I haven't seen any documentation which says this may be a problem.

Can someone please help review my code for any obvious mistakes? Thanks in advance!

### Component File:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}"/>
<div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aura:id="modalbox" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium">Create Case</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="medium" class="{! v.isLoading ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide' }"/>
            <aura:if isTrue="{! v.isOpen }">
                <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
            </aura:if>
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.closeModal}" />
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" aura:id="backdrop"></div>
</aura:component>
```

### Controller:

```
({
handleStatusChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    if (event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
        // Flow finished successfully; close the modal
        component.set("v.isOpen", false);
    }
},
closeModal : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Close the modal
    component.set("v.isOpen", false);
},
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Launch the flow when the component initializes
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    flow.startFlow("Create_Case");
}
})
```

### The outcome after I click the "New" action:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to exactly achieve? You can perfectly fine use only flow to create custom record creation, also you are using aura components -> which basically should be treated as deprecated and LWC should be used.

Comment: @user1974566 The Flow we have built is sufficient, but I would like to optimise the user experience. I would like the Flow to a) override the standard "NewCase" action, so that whenever anybody wants to create a new Case (even from a related list), it always runs the Flow, and b) open in a modal (pop-up), so the User is not forced to navigate away from the page they are currently on. To do both these things, I believe I have to wrap the Flow in an Aura Component, as LWCs are not yet supported in Lightning Action Overrides.